# Does returned struct of localtime() need to be freed?

Tags: c, memory-management, function-prototypes

```
struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
```

I checked `man localtime` but there's no words on whether it's my duty to clean it after using.

And in fact I have many similar doubts on functions returning a pointer, how do you determine it should be freed or not ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is the result struct of localtime allocated in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694365/how-is-the-result-struct-of-localtime-allocated-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This information should be in the man page - my `localtime` man page says:

> The return value points to a
>   statically allocated struct...

Statically allocated objects should not be passed to `free()`, so this is your answer - no, you should *not* free the return value of `localtime()`.

The only way to tell in the general case is to consult the documentation or implementation of the function in question.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned about functions that return pointers to static data - they are frequently not thread-safe, and it's good practice to avoid them, even if your code is not *yet* used in a multithreaded environment.

It's better to use the `_r` form of these functions, i.e. `localtime_r()`