# How is the result struct of localtime allocated in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I was playing with the `time.h` file in C that helps us with time/day functions.

I came across:

```
struct tm * _Cdecl localtime(const time_t *__timer);
```

...which seems to return a pointer to tm struct. I have found that return by address is mostly used to return new memory allocations.

If this is so, how does the above return actually work (the return address of a `struct tm`). Is the returned object defined somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: You define and allocate the tm struct ***in your code.*** localtime( ) stores its output in that struct and returns a pointer to that same struct. This might seem redundant but it's handy at times to get the pointer back, even though you know where the struct is.

Comment: @PeteWilson - Um, no, you don't. Please see the answers below. What you describe is only the case in the `_r` version of the call (`localtime_r()`) from SUSv2 or the `_s` version of the call in MSVC

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does returned struct of localtime() need to be freed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210880/does-returned-struct-of-localtime-need-to-be-freed)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The pointer returned by `localtime` (and some other functions) are actually pointers to statically allocated memory. **So you do not need to free it, and you should not free it.**

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/

> This structure is statically allocated and shared by the functions
> gmtime and localtime. Each time either one of these functions is
> called the content of this structure is overwritten.

**EDIT :** Appending a few things mentioned in the comments.

A direct result of this shared data-structure is that `localtime` and similar functions are not thread-safe. The thread-safe solution varies with different platforms. [`localtime_r` for POSIX](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime_r) and [`localtime_s` for MSVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a442x3ye%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth actually it has, read (C99, 7.23.3 Time conversions functions) "Except for the strftime function, these functions each return a pointer to one of two types of static objects [...] Execution of any of the functions that return a pointer to one of these object types may overwrite the information in any object of the same type pointed to by the value returned from any previous call to any of them."

Comment: Might also be good to point out that because of this, it isn't threadsafe and the `_r` versions of these calls are.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yes, that's a very good point. Interestingly, I can't find the `_r` versions outside of the linux man pages. Nor does it appear in MSVC. Is it a compiler extension?

Comment: @Mysticial - SUSv2; http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/localtime.html . I don't do windows, so I have no idea what the equiv is or if it exists

Comment: @Mysticial: for MSVC there's the equivalent `_s` version (with parameters swapped); the `_r` version isn't in the C standard, but it's defined in the Standard UNIX Specification (the man pages refer to SUSv2).

Answer (score 13):

It returns a pointer to a piece of statically allocated memory (probably either a `static` variable defined inside `localtime` or a global defined somewhere in the C runtime library). You must not free such memory.

Obviously this function is not reentrant (but can be thread-safe if TLS is used).

You must be careful when using this pointer: never make any function calls that could call `localtime`/`gmtime`/... before you finished using that pointer, otherwise the content of the memory referenced by your pointer could change (in response to the new call to `localtime`) and you will be reading values relative to another `time_t`.

In general the design of the date/time library is quite outdated, this kind of optimization was worthwhile when the C language was designed, nowadays it only gives problems.

To address these problems there are at least two different improved versions of these functions: `localtime_r` (SUSv2, `r` stays for "reentrant") and `localtime_s` (Microsoft, `s` stays for "safe"). The sad fact for portability is that these do almost the same thing (they require the destination `struct tm` to be passed as a parameter), but differ in name and ordering of the parameters.

Comment: Note: `localtime_s()` is also detailed in C11 spec: normative section K.3.8.2.4.  Not certain if MS (or anyone) meets that C11 specification.

Comment: Wow, good thing you said that! I was doing exactly that: measuring `date_before` and `date_after` and comparing them. And now as it turns out I was comparing the same variable! I confirm that printing address of `date_before` and `date_after` gives the same value.

Answer (score 5):

The [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) says:

> The return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

Also:

> The localtime_r() function does the same, but stores the data in a user-supplied struct. It need not set tzname, timezone, and daylight.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `localtime` usually returns the address of a static object. I suspect it looks like this:

```
struct tm *
localtime(const time_t *timer)
{
    static struct tm tm;

    /* Magic. */

    return &tm;
}
```

Comment: You are missing an `&` I believe

Comment: There are no objects in C :)

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian I am using the word "object" in the same sense the standard is using it.

Comment: Note: `gmtime()` _may_ return the address of the same `static struct tm;` as `localtime()`.

Answer (score 3):

They return a pointer to a static struct local to the library. From the man page:

```
NOTES

The  four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return
a pointer to static data and hence are  not  thread-safe.   Thread-safe
versions asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r() and localtime_r() are spec‐
ified by SUSv2, and available since libc 5.2.5.

POSIX.1-2001 says: "The asctime(), ctime(), gmtime(),  and  localtime()
functions  shall  return values in one of two static objects: a broken-
down time structure and an array of type char.  Execution of any of the
functions  may  overwrite  the  information returned in either of these
objects by any of the other functions."  This can occur  in  the  glibc
implementation.
```

Comment: man pages are a wonderful thing. At the time SO wasn't showing me that anyone else had answered so I figured I'd just post the relevant docs.

Answer (score 0):

The pointed object that is returned by `localtime` function has static storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Just test it:

```
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  while (1) {
    time_t t = time(0);
    localtime(&t);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

On my system the memory stays the same.