# Is there any memory leakeage in this code?

Tags: c++, c, memory-leaks

I have this code:

```
 int tim=10000; // some random number
 tm *now=localtime(&tim);
 printf("Date is %d/%02d/%02d\n", now->tm_year+1900, now->tm_mon+1, now->tm_mday);
 printf("Time is %02d:%02d\n", now->tm_hour, now->tm_min);
```

The reason that I am wondering if it has memory leak is that localtime returns a pointer to a struct which means that it allocate memory. but nobody release it.

Is there any memory leak on this code?

Comment: Can you show us what happens within `localtime`?

Comment: You should rather use `time_t` instead of an integer

Comment: this function is dangerous. it uses a static variable, which means it's not thread safe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694365/how-is-the-result-struct-of-localtime-allocated-in-c

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: The type time_t
      include: <time.h>
       Is exactly identical to "int" in behaviour. You may assign int values
       to a time_t variable, and vice-versa, and print time_t values using
       the %d format, and everything. From this site: http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/time.html

Comment: @mans, you just stopped reading when the interesting part begins. It may happen to be `int` on many archs, but that is not guaranteed, so better use the standardized type for it.

Comment: try switching to `struct tm * localtime_r(time_t * tim, struct tm * output)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't (and shall not) have to explicitly free anything as `localtime` returns a pointer to a static object.

C Standard says:

> (C11, 7.27.3 Time conversion functions p1) "Except for the strftime function, these functions each return a pointer to one of two types of static objects: a broken-down time structure or an array of char."

And from [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) documentation,

> The asctime(), ctime(), gmtime(), and localtime() functions shall return values in one of two static objects: a broken-down time structure and an array of type char. Execution of any of the functions may overwrite the information returned in either of these objects by any of the other functions.

Comment: Your wording `There is no need` reads rather dangerous, I think freeing will most probably cause problems.

Comment: @Wolf I modified the wording